# invalid character in golang for connection to mysql

Tags: go

i am new using golang and try to connect to mySql

here my source code. and when i run this example code i got error. the error detail are below the source code

```
package main

import "database/sql"
import "fmt"
import _"github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"

type trade_history struct {
        id, final_meta_report_id, trading_account_id, lp, lp2, lp3             int
        symbol, price, price_type, time, type, status, created_at, updated_at  string
        qty, pegged_distance, price_limit                                      double
}
var db *sql.DB
var err error

funct getTradingHistory (final_Meta_report_ID int) (err error){
        db, err = sql.Open("mysql", username:password@trade.asdewx134.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/trading_dashboard
        defer db.Close()
        if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err.Error())
        }
        err = db.Ping()
        if err != nil{
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        }
        var p trade_history
        err = db.QueryRow("select id, final_meta_report_id, trading_account_id, symbol, qty, price, price_type, time, lp, lp2, lp3, pegged_distance, price_limit, time_limit, type, status, created_at, u$
        if err !=nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        }
        fmt.Printf("id: %d\n Final_meta_report_id: %d\n trading_account_id: %d\n symbol: %s\n qty: %.2f\n price: %s\n price_type: %s\n time: %s\n lp: %d\n lp2: %d\n lp3: %d\n pegged_distance: %.2f\n pr$

        return err
}

func main(){
        getTradingHistory(2074)
}
```

i got error like this one

```
# command-line-arguments
./myConnectionMySql.go:9:35: syntax error: unexpected type, expecting name
./myConnectionMySql.go:15:1: syntax error: non-declaration statement outside function body
./myConnectionMySql.go:16:56: invalid character U+0040 '@'
./myConnectionMySql.go:26:2: syntax error: non-declaration statement outside function body
./myConnectionMySql.go:30: newline in string
```

how to fix this problem ?

Comment: A error message of the form `./myConnectionMySql.go:9:35` means you have an error on line 9, column 35. Look there and see what "unexpected type, expecting name" could mean here. Hint `type` is a _reserved_ word. Same with `./myConnectionMySql.go:15:1`: What do you think `funct` should be? And so on.

Comment: Please take the Tour of Go once more and just fix all the typos the compiler reports with exact line and column numbers.

Comment: Can you fix your code in the question. There are unclosed paranthesis and quotes in it. If this is the exact copy of the code you are running, then ur issue is the obvious unclosed paranthesis in the `sql.Open` statement and the unclosed string quote in the `db.QueryRow` statement. Also I think the second argument to the `sql.Open` should be a string.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this, the codes have comment on them, you can read it and adapt to your needs.

```
package main

import "database/sql"
import "fmt"
import _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"

type trade_history struct {
    // best practice in golang is to name your field in upper camel case if you intend to export it
    // or lower camel case if you don't.
    id, final_meta_report_id, trading_account_id, lp, lp2, lp3 int
    // `type` is reserved keyword, therefore for example, i use `ptype`
    symbol, price, price_type, time, ptype, status, created_at, updated_at string
    qty, pegged_distance, price_limit                                      double
}

// you don't need to declare global variable like this, if you want it to be accessible to all your packages
// it's best to use struct.
// var db *sql.DB
// var err error -- this one is shadowed by declaration of err in your getTradingHistory anyway.

func getTradingHistory(reportId int) (err error) {
    // Your dsn is unquoted hence error
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "username:password@trade.asdewx134.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/trading_dashboard")
    // your trade data is here

    defer db.Close()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }
    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }
    var th trade_history
    // this one is also unquoted and your SQL statement is not correct
    // here i add `FROM [YOUR TABLE] that you can edit to your needs`
    err = db.QueryRow("select id, final_meta_report_id, trading_account_id, symbol, qty, price, price_type, time, lp, lp2, lp3, pegged_distance, price_limit, time_limit, type, status, created_at FROM [YOUR TABLE] WHERE id = ?", reportId).Scan( /* Scan your fields here */ ) // This is where you should scan your fields.
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Printf("id: %d\n Final_meta_report_id: %d\n trading_account_id: %d\n symbol: %s\n qty: %.2f\n price: %s\n price_type: %s\n time: %s\n lp: %d\n lp2: %d\n lp3: %d\n pegged_distance: %.2f\n pr$")
    return err
}

func main() {
    getTradingHistory(2074)
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You should fix the bugs, look the code comments as below:

```
package main

import "database/sql"
import "fmt"
import _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"

type trade_history struct {
    id, final_meta_report_id, trading_account_id, lp, lp2, lp3 int
    symbol, price, price_type, time, typeField, status, created_at, updated_at string
    qty, pegged_distance, price_limit                                          double
}

var db *sql.DB

var err error


func getTradingHistory(final_Meta_report_ID int) (err error) {
    host := "trade.asdewx134.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com"
    port := 3306
    db := "trading_dashboard"

    //use Sprintf if you wanna parse a string with values
    conn := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@%s:%s/%s", username, password, host, port, db)
    db, err = sql.Open("mysql", conn)
    defer db.Close()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }
    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }
    var p trade_history

    //if you have multiple lines of texts use ` instead of "
    err = db.QueryRow(`select id, final_meta_report_id, 
    trading_account_id, symbol, qty, price, price_type, time, lp, 
    lp2, lp3, pegged_distance, price_limit, time_limit, type, status, created_at`).Scan(&p)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }


    fmt.Printf("id: %d\n Final_meta_report_id: %d\n trading_account_id: %d\n symbol: %s\n qty: %.2f\n price: %s\n price_type: %s\n time: %s\n lp: %d\n lp2: %d\n lp3: %d\n pegged_distance: %.2f\n")

    return err
}

func main() {
    getTradingHistory(2074)
}
```

Comment: Lead by example and gofmt the code in your answer. `\n` isn't a newline in backtick string literals. QueryRow does not return an error.

Comment: @Peter Thanks for spotting that, the problems solved